# Write Java Comparator

Tags: java, vector, sorting, comparator

I have created a Vector object to store data in `Table` object as `Vector<Table>`. `Vector<Table>` contains components as below.

```
[Vector<Record> records, String tableName, String keyColumnName, int recordCount, int columnCount]
```

I need to sort `tableName` in above Vector to my own order and return `Vector<Table>` with `sorted tableNames` for other processes.

I have wrote method as below.

```
private Vector<Table> orderTables(Vector<Table> loadTables) {

    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Table table : loadTables) {

        String tblName = table.getTableName();
        tableNames.add(tblName);

    }
    Collections.sort(tableNames, new MyComparable());

    return null;
}
```

But I have no idea about how to write `Comparator` to this. My own sort order is stored in `.properties` file. I can read it and get value. But I have no idea about how to compare it.

How could I do it?

Comment: Your code looks not good. Why don't you use `List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();` instead of yours. Just 1 example in your code.

Comment: @Bishan could you please explain this part: "My own sort order is stored in .properties file". Does it mean that you have multiple possible sorting modes (sort acending, sort descending) and this mode is stored as property value?

Comment: @dbf `My own sort order is stored in .properties file` means i'm maintaining `java properties` file. and i stored data like `database username ,password` in there. also i have stored `sort order`, that i need to sort in there. as example, 
`SORT_ORDER = SALES,SALE_PRODUCTS,EXPENSES,EXPENSES_ITEMS`. i need to sort data in my `tableNames` List according to above order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Before clarification

You need to write a `Comparator` for `Table` objects that delegates to the `tableName`'s comparator:

```
new Comparator<Table>() {
    @Override public int compare(Table one, Table two) {
        return one.getTableName().compareTo(two.getTableName());
    }
}
```

**Note that** this will consider `Table`s that have the same name to be equal. This can mess things up if you put these tables in a `HashMap` or `HashSet`. To avoid this, you can detect this case and return `one.hashCode() - two.hashCode()` if the table names are the same.

[Guava's `ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) is a convenient way to write such multi-stage comparisons:

```
new Comparator<Table>() {
    @Override public int compare(Table one, Table two) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
                 .compare(one.getTableName(), two.getTableName())
                 .compare(one.hashCode(), two.hashCode())
                 .result();
    }
}
```

## After clarification

Okay, the question is to impose a predefined sorting order rather than sorting the `Table`s by name. In that case, you need to make a `Comparator` that is aware of the ordering defined in the `.properties` file.

One way to achieve this is to initialize a mapping of table names to sorting order indices, and refer that mapping during the comparison. Given the property value:

`SORT_ORDER = SALES,SALE_PRODUCTS,EXPENSES,EXPENSES_ITEMS`

The mapping should look like:

```
{
    SALES: 0,
    SALE_PRODUCTS: 1,
    EXPENSES: 2,
    EXPENSES_ITEMS: 3
}
```

Here's what the comparator would look like:

```
private static class PredefinedOrderComparator implements Comparator<Table> {

    public PredefinedOrderComparator() {

        // Initialize orderIndex here

    }

    private final Map<String, Integer> orderIndex;

    @Override public int compare(Table one, Table two) {
        return orderIndex.get(one.getTableName()) - orderIndex.get(two.getTableName());
    } 

}
```

#### To populate `orderIndex` from the property value, you need to:

1. Get the comma-separated list using `getProperty()` as you mentioned
2. Split that value on comma (I recommend using [Guava's `Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html), but [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or others will work too)
3. Initialize a new `HashMap<String, Integer>` and an `int index = 0`
4. Iterate through the split tokens, map the current token to `index` and increment `index`

**Note the implicit assumption that none of the table names have a comma in it.**

Comment: i have done as above. and tried to call `Collections.sort()` as `PredefinedOrderComparator poc = new PredefinedOrderComparator();
  Collections.sort(tableNames, poc);`. but i't gave error as `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>, PredefinedOrderComparator)`

Comment: This is a `Comparator` for `Table` objects, so you'll want to use it to sort `loadTables` in your example, not `tableNames`.

If you want to sort `tableNames`, then you need to change `PredefinedOrderComparator` to be a `Comparator<String>` instead and  change the `compare` method a little bit to fit the new definition.

Comment: I tested your example by hard cording values as `orderIndex.put("SALES", 0);
  orderIndex.put("SALE_PRODUCTS", 1);`. it's worked. i have stored sort order in properties file as `SORT_ORDER = SALES,SALE_PRODUCTS,EXPENSES,EXPENSES_ITEMS`. how cold i add this to HashMap? i can get value of `SORT_ORDER` using `getProperty()` method. but it returns value as `SALES,SALE_PRODUCTS,EXPENSES,EXPENSES_ITEM`.

Comment: Cool! I updated my answer with instructions on initializing `orderIndex` from the property value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MyComparable implements Comparator<Table>{
   @Override
   public int compare(Table table1, Table table2) {
    return (table1.getTableName().compareTo(table2.getTableName());
   }
 }
```

make sure that you have overridden the hashcode and equals in Table class to achieve this.

Comment: and Vectors are Synchronized and therefore its slow in terms of performance. Do you need this synchronization if not consider using a much for efficient non sync collection type such as a List

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a very simple example on how to work with a Comparator. If you create a class called Main, copy paste below contents in it, compile and run it, you can see what's going on.

A comparator just needs to implement an interface. For this it needs to implement one method (public int compare(T arg0, T arg1). There you specify how a collection will get sorted; in this case according to the alfabet.

I hope this helps you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start\n");
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for(String s : new String[]{"mzeaez", "xcxv", "hjkhk", "azasq", "iopiop"}) {
            items.add(createItem(s));
        }
        System.out.println("Items before sort:");
        System.out.println(Item.toString(items));
        Collections.sort(items, new ItemComparator());
        System.out.println("Items after sort:");
        System.out.println(Item.toString(items));
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    private static Item createItem(String s) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setS(s);
        return item;
    }

}

class Item {

    private String s;

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item: " + s;
    }

    public static String toString(Collection<Item> items) {
        String s = "";
        for(Item item : items) {
            s += item + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }    

}

class ItemComparator implements Comparator<Item> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
        return item1.getS().compareTo(item2.getS());
    }

}
```